# How to archive scatterplot with randomly jittered x-values for visualization purpose?

Tags: plotting, graphics, fitting

I want to fit my data or just plot a figure with randomly jittered x-values like this:
[image]

Here I give an example:

```
A = 0.52;
Kf = 0.77;
f[r_] := (r - A)/((r - A) + Kf);
Plot[f[r], {r, 0, 100}]
```

But I could only get the figure like this below without the x-values appearence I want.
[image]
Who could help me to solve it ?

I wanna the value on the x axis to be randomly jittered like {0,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000} in the paper figure.

Not fitting question, thanks all!

Thanks for your kindness !

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor. To get started, 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,

Comment: 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You need to provide some more information to make this question clear. What data are you trying to fit? Can you give a sample? Or are you trying to extract the data from the plot? Or are you trying to create some "pseudo" data based on the plot? Be careful randomly jittering data could also be considered as data falsification, if used in the wrong way, which is a scientific no go! I will vote to close this until you have improved the post so someone can answer.

Comment: @Dunlop Thanks for you remindness. It's my first time to ask a question here. I'm sorry to bother you and I'll try to improve my post.  Here I want to make a statement: The figure with randomly jittered x-value is from a paper, I just want to learn how to draw it like this way. I'd be approciate if you could be more pattient and friendly. Thanks !

Comment: Try `ListPlot` to plot your data and `Show` to combine it with the plot in your question.

Comment: Thanks ! But I have got my answer now and I have try to improve my question. It looks better now and much of us could understand now I guess. Thanks for your remindness ! Best wishes !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ScalingFunctions` function

```mathematica
A = 0.52;
Kf = 0.77;
f[r_] := (r - A)/((r - A) + Kf);
Plot[f[r],
 {r, 0, 100},
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks !
This is what did I want, it works!
Thanks so much !

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The underlying model

```
A = 0.52;
Kf = 0.77;
f[r_] := (r - A)/((r - A) + Kf);
```

Generating noisy data to be fitted

```
SeedRandom[1234];
data = {#, f[#] + RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}]} & /@ RandomReal[100, 10];
```

Fitting the data to the model

```
(nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, (r - a)/((r - a) + k), 
  {a, k}, r])["BestFitParameters"]

(* {a -> 0.554078, k -> 0.724629} *)
```

Plotting the fit along with the data

```
Plot[nlm[r], {r, 0, 100},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer so much!
It's my fault that I haven't state my question clearly.
I'm so sorry about that.
What I want is the value on the x-axis jittered, which is used for visulization purpose.
Not the fitting problem, thanks.
I'll reedit my question now.